# case sensitive jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, case-sensitive

My problem is a bit tricky. I am using an `Editable JComboBox`. It may contain case sensitive items. For example, it may have `Item1` and `item1`. So, these two items should be treated as different in my case.

But the problem is, these two items is treated as same. No matter which Items I have selected, it always select the first one (`Item1`). I've searched in Google, but didn't find any solution. That's why, I am here.

**Code:**

```
//loading of Items
jdcbmItemType = new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(ItemTypeHandler.getItemTypeComboData(MainFrame.companyId));

private void jcbItemTypeMouseReleased(MouseEvent evt)
{
    if (jcbItemType.getSelectedIndex() != -1)
    {
        loadItemTypeDetails(((ItemObject) jcbItemType.getSelectedItem()).getId());
    }
    else
    {
        resetFields();
    }
}

public static Vector<ItemObject> getItemTypeComboDataV(BigInteger companyId, BigInteger categoryId, boolean addFirstElement, TriState deleted) throws ExceptionWrapper, EJBException
{
    try
    {            
        return (Vector<ItemObject>)lookupItemTypeFacade().getItemTypeComboData(companyId, categoryId, addFirstElement, deleted);
    } catch (ExceptionWrapper exceptionWrapper)
    {
        throw exceptionWrapper;
    } catch (EJBException ejbEx)
    {
        throw ejbEx;
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ExceptionWrapper(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

`ItemObject` is a customClass where one field is `BigInteger` and another is `String`.

`getItemTypeComboData` is functioning properly. So, you can assume to get a list of `ItemObject` from here and it will nicely convert it to `Vector<ItemObject>`

`jcbItemType.getSelectedIndex()` always return the same index for `Item1` and `item1`. But it returns different index for `item2`.

I know, it would be better if I can use `itemStateChanged` event. But in my case, I can't use it. But my question is, `MouseReleased` and `FocusLost` works fine for different name string but not same string with different case. I am really stumbled.

**Another way to ask the question:**

Does `MouseReleased` or `FocusLost` event check for case-sensitive items?

How to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it have any solution? Experts, please advise.

Comment: Please post your full code. It would make more sense than words. Also, did you see this warning while adding new item in `JComboBox` : `Warning: Focus and keyboard navigation problems may arise if you add duplicate String objects. A workaround is to add new objects instead of String objects and make sure that the toString() method is defined.`

Comment: You have not shown the code for `ItemTypeHandler.getItemTypeComboData(MainFrame.companyId)`. Read the above warning message I posted.

Comment: @Subs:I check your warning message, `toString()` is defined.

Comment: Sorry your code is incomplete. I don't see a `toString()` method in your code for `ItemObject` nor do I understand whether `jcbItemTypeMouseReleased(MouseEvent evt)`  is an `actionevent` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and this works fine , If this is not what youre looking for, then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better sooner help!

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ComboBoxTest {

    JComboBox combo;
    JTextField txt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComboBoxTest();
    }

    public ComboBoxTest() {
        String items[] = {"Item1", "item1"};
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboBox Case-sensitivity Test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        combo = new JComboBox(items);
        combo.setEditable(true);

        txt = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(combo);
        panel.add(txt);
        frame.add(panel);
        combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                String str = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();
                txt.setText(str);
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention. I am using `MouseReleased` event to get the selected item.

Comment: Isn't it possible with `MouseReleased` instead of `itemStateChanged` ?

Comment: This is a special case. I need to use it because of heavy information loading during different item changed event. So, I want when a user fully select an item (since it is an editable jcombobox), the info will be loaded then. but if i use `itemStateChanged`, then the heavy information will be loaded on each character typing, which is slower.

Comment: @sarwar026 How do you suppose you get `MouseReleased` event while you edit the `JComboBox` ?? :-)

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. I am using `MouseReleased` for selecting item with mouse pointer and `FocusLost` event for selecting item with typing. I have handled both mouse and keyboard event.

Comment: Does `MouseReleased` or `FocusLost` event check for case-sensitive items?

Comment: @sarwar026 I still cant find your SSCCE! Without an SSCCE I'll no longer look into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing like this :-

```
String[] items = {"item1", "item2"};
JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(items);
cb.setEditable(true);
```

Now you have to access the JCombobox elements which you have insert into this as in array form like this:-
    MyItemListener actionListener = new MyItemListener();
    cb.addItemListener(actionListener);

```
class MyItemListener implements ItemListener {
// This method is called only if a new item has been selected.
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();

    // Get the affected item
    Object item = evt.getItem();

    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        // Item was just selected
    } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
        // Item is no longer selected
    }
    }
 }
```

After adding the itemListener you can do your different tasks with individual JCombobox Item

Comment: Please read my question once again. I have done all those you have said. But my problem is in `case-sensitivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works fine...

use ActionListener() to capture the click... then use getSelectedItem() to capture the item clicked on the JComboBox

try this,

check in your console for the output

```
myComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
            String str = (String) myComboBox.getSelectedItem();
           System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Comment: It's not possible in my case. I've to use `MouseReleased` and `FocusLost` event to capture this change.

Comment: You can do one thing, get the item of the JCombo box, and do a toString() on them, then try to compare it using .equals() , that will give be case-sensitive.

Comment: But `getSelectedIndex()` is not changing when I select a different Item of same name with different case.